# Mysql query group data in a field

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE `users_customers`(
    `user_id` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `customer_id` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`user_id`, `customer_id`),
    INDEX user_id_index (`user_id`),
    INDEX customer_index (`customer_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customers`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

With data

```
users_customers
user_id       customer_id
--------------------------
1             1
2             1
1             2
1             3
2             3
...
```

I would like to query from this table and produce results like this

```
user_id        customers
-------------------------
1              1,2,3
2              1,3
...
```

I have looked at concat() function, but still don't know how to reflect what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You an use [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function to do this. It will group the values and return them as a string.

So your query would be something like

```
SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(customers)
  FROM users_customers GROUP BY user_id
```

If you want the values in a certain order, you can add `ORDER BY` into the `GROUP_CONCAT`, or if you want a different separator than comma, you can add `SEPARATOR` definition.

You can also prepend the column with `DISTINCT` if the field may contain duplicate values and you only want them once.

```
SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT customers ORDER BY customers DESC SEPARATOR ';')
  FROM users_customers GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: Returns as a csv string, not an array.

Comment: actually it returns them as a string delimited by whatever you choose, it just defaults to comma.

Comment: according to this http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/ you actually need to place the order by outside group_concat() function though, but thanks for the direction, I have resolved my problem

Comment: @lightbringer If you want to order the column(s) inside the `GROUP_CONCAT`, you place the `ORDER BY` inside it. If you want to order the rows returned, for example by user_id, you place it outside. The functionality is different based on where the `ORDER BY` is.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)**

```
SELECT user_id,GROUP_CONCAT(customer_id)
FROM users_customers
GROUP BY user_id
```

**[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dad83/2)**